# Check if a blob exist in a path in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

lets say i want to upload a blob in a container-> `azureblob`

path: `123/human/a.json`

i want to check if any blob exist in path: `123/human/`

i couldn't find any good resource for this.

Found this in c# [How to check wether a CloudBlobDirectory exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189344/how-to-check-wether-a-cloudblobdirectory-exists-or-not)

couldn't find anything on node

Comment: hope [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs) helps

Comment: Do you want to check the existence of a specific blob in a directory or any blob in a directory?

Comment: any blob in the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is check the existence of any blob in a virtual directory, you can use **`listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix`** method in SDK and try to list the blobs. If the count of results you get is more than zero, that means blobs are present in the directory. For example, take a look at the sample code:

```
blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix('azureblob', '123/human/', null, {
  delimiter: '',
  maxReults: 1
}, function(error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    const entries = result.entries;
    if (entries.length > 0) {
      console.log('Blobs exist in directory...');
    } else {
      console.log('No blobs exist in directory...');
    }
  }
});
```

If you're looking for existence of a specific blob in a virtual directory, you can simply use **`doesBlobExist`** method of the SDK. For example, take a look at the sample code:

```
blobService.doesBlobExist('azureblob', '123/human/a.json', function(error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    if (result.exists) {
      console.log('Blob exists...');
    } else {
      console.log('Blob does not exist...');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can you do this in a synchronous way?

Answer (score 0):

Since doesBlobExist returns a Promise, you can try following implementation:

**

```
export async function doesBlobExist(
  connectionString,
  containerName,
  blobFileName
): Promise<boolean> {
  const promise: Promise<boolean> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const blobService = azure.createBlobService(connectionString);
      
      blobService.doesBlobExist(containerName, blobFileName, function (
        error,
        result
      ) {
        if (!error) {
          resolve(result.exists);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(new Error(err));
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

**